# Python: break out of for loop calling a function

Tags: python

I need to break out of a `for` loop according to the result obtained after calling a function. This is an example of what I'm after (does not work obviously):

```
def break_out(i):
    # Some condition
    if i > 10:
        # This does not work.
        return break

for i in range(1000):
    # Call function
    break_out(i)
```

Of course this is a *very simple* `MWE`, my actual function is much bigger which is why I move it outside of the `for` loop.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19425818/1391441) says it is not possible and I should make the function return a boolean and add an `if` statement inside the `for` loop to decide.

Since it's a rather old question and it didn't get much attention (also, it's applied to `while` loops), I'd like to re-check if something like this is possible.

Comment: Why is the linked answer not suitable?

Comment: @SiHa I didn't say it is not suitable, I am asking if there's a more _direct_ way of doing it (as opposed to returning a flag and adding an `if` block).

Comment: Nope, no new way of doing it - previous question still applies

Comment: @Gabriel We're talking about a difference of *one line* here. And, to be honest, your example (if it did work) would be harder to debug because it's not obvious *within the loop* that something might exit it early.

Comment: @SiHa I know it's one line (or very few) but my question aimed at learning new possibilities rather than saving a handful of lines. Your point on debugging has value, perhaps add an answer giving this as a reason why it is _not_ (or should not be) possible to do what I asked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not (reasonably) possible.  You could raise an exception, I suppose, but then you'll have to catch it with a `try`/`except` statement outside the loop.

Since OP has expressed curiosity about this, I'm going to explain *why* Python doesn't allow you to do this.  Functions are supposed to be [composable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composability) elements.  They're meant to work in different contexts.

Allowing a function to break out of a loop has two separate problems:

1. Client code might not expect this behavior.
2. What if there is no loop?

For (1), if I read some code like this:

```
import foo  # some library I didn't write

while condition:
    foo.bar()
assert not condition
```

I reasonably assume the assertion will not fire.  But if `foo.bar()` was able to break out of the loop, it could.

For (2), perhaps I wrote this somewhere else:

```
if condition:
    foo.bar()
```

It's not clear what that should do if `foo.bar()` tries to break out of the loop, since there is no loop.

Comment: Why not add a try/except _inside_ the loop? And then put a break in the except?

Comment: @logic: An `if` is less typing.

Comment: True, raising errors is a bad method.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `return break`, return a value that forces a break condition.  To extend your example:

```
def break_out(i):
    # Some condition
    return i > 10  # Returns `True` if you should break from loop.


for i in range(1000):
    # Call function
    if break_out(i):
        break

    # Insert the rest of your code here...
```

Comment: Yep, this is what the OP mentions in his question and also asks if it can be done differently.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was trying to avoid (also it's pretty much exactly the answer in the question linked) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ack! Egg on my face.  This answer popped into my head so quickly that I skimmed the rest of the question. Sorry!